# C# Async FileInfo Extensions (Copy, Move, Delete)

Tags: c#, .net, file-system, io, async-await

Here is my effort to implement extensions for `FileInfo` object:

```csharp
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static async Task MoveFileAsync(this FileInfo file, string destinationPath, string destinationFileName = "")
    {
        await CopyFileAsync(file, destinationPath, destinationFileName).ContinueWith((x) =>
        {
            DeleteFileAsync(file);
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);
    }

    public static async Task CopyFileAsync(this FileInfo file, string destinationPath, string destinationFileName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationFileName))
        {
            destinationFileName = file.Name;
        }

        using (FileStream SourceStream = file.Open(FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(Path.Combine(destinationPath, destinationFileName)))
            {
                await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Task DeleteFileAsync(this FileInfo file)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (File.Exists(file.FullName))
            {
                File.Delete(file.FullName);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The idea was to make it efficient, and basically, allow deleting in the background.

It feels like I mix things, but not sure what exactly is wrong.

So, I have a couple of questions for the beginning:

1. The implementation of `MoveFileAsync`:

   - Is this the right way to implement it? I wanted to call the `CopyFileAsync` and when it is completed -> call `DeleteFileAsync`.
   - Do I need to add `return` before `DeleteFileAsync(file);`? (So that the method will return a task).
2. The next step is using this `DeleteFileAsync` method within a loop. Like this:

```csharp
public Task EmptyWorkingFolder()
{
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(/*my-directory-path*/);
    var deleteTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in directory.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        deleteTasks.Add(file.DeleteFileAsync());
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(deleteTasks);
}
```

Now my question is, how useful is this in comparison to just deleting the files synchronously?

Comment: Few tips: 1) `if (File.Exists(file.FullName))` a redundant check, look into `File.Delete` documentation. 2) there's no sense to make disk operations concurrent because file system anyway does all the jobs sequentially for single drive. Run one `Task` for all the Delete operations if you need to `await` it. Measure and compare the performance of the different implementations to be sure. 3) don't mix continuations with async/await approach. 4) names for the local variables must begin with lower-cased letter.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @aepot. Could you please explain more about number 3?

Comment: For example this `await CopyFileAsync(file, destinationPath, destinationFileName).ContinueWith((x) => { DeleteFileAsync(file); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);` can be this `await CopyFileAsync(file, destinationPath, destinationFileName); DeleteFileAsync(file);` with exactly the same behavior. Continuations and async/await provides the same features but simply looks differently. Mixed code is harder to read.

Comment: @aepot, now I see how it mixed, and I understand the example, however, how I will have to use 2 `await`s in a row (for copy and for delete). So I think that it's better to use `Task.WhenAll()` to prevent losing errors.

Comment: @aepot, those comments seem to be _reviewing the code_, and therefore better presented using an answer.  And you'll earn reputation points that way!